# AWS Amplify for Swift / SwiftUI under Combine framework cause headache

Tags: swift, sample, combine, aws-amplify

Does anybody have a working copy/sample of using AWS Amplify with the Combine framework?

The samples provided
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/ios
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/ios#configure-auth-category
Seems really straight forward and I'm using it verbatim, but since I'm not well versed in Combine, it could be that I'm losing the sink, especially when these functions are placed in an Observable class.

And when going with URL session, my attempts deliver a load of the same error:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example showing how to sign in with username and password:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Amplify

enum AuthState {
  case signUp
  case login
  case confirmCode(email: String)
  case session(user: AuthUser)
}

final class SessionManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published var authState: AuthState = .login
  var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  func getCurrentAuthUser() {
    if let user = Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.authState = .session(user: user)
      }
    } else {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.authState = .login
      }
    }
  }

  func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
    Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: email, password: password)
      .resultPublisher
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .sink(
        receiveCompletion: {
          if case .failure(let error) = $0 {
            print("Sign in error: \(error)")
          }
        }) { result in
        self.getCurrentAuthUser()
      }.store(in: &self.storage)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when testing on a simulator, however testing on a device eliminated it.

Also, Don’s example shows how to handle the result of the `sink` call with `.store(in: &self.storage)`. This is required and the amplify docs don’t show that very well.